# Issues with overriding the Opportunity New button

Tags: apex

When I try to override the new button, I get an error, and it looks like the record was trying to be saved.  What's going on ?

Here's the code

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="OpportunityController" action="{!oppRenamer}" >

</apex:page>
```

apex

```
public OpportunityController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        string url = ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl() ;      
        this.oppId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

        if (this.oppId != null){
            //do  pre existing stuff
        }
        }else{
            //do nothing. this is the case of a new opp being created.
        }


    }


    public PageReference oppRenamer() {
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/006/e');
        Map<String, String> m = pr.getParameters();
        // Keep existing parameters
        m.putAll(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters());
        // Add Opportunity name parameter
        m.put('opp3', 'DO NOT MODIFY');
        // Turn off the override so you go to the default UI page (and not an infinite loop)
        m.put('nooverride', '1');
        if  (m.keySet().contains('save_new')){
            m.remove('save_new');
            m.put('save_new', '0');
        }
        return pr;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `save_new` parameter was messing it up. when i just remove it, it works.